# Data passed into underscore template is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js

As mentioned in title, when data is referenced inside of the html template it is undefined.

JS:

```
   var data = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        data.push(rows[i]);
        if (i == rows.length - 1) {
            fs.readFile('tree.html', 'utf8', function (err, html) {
                console.log(data);
                var template = _.template(html);
                var result = template({ data: data }); 
                res.send(result);
            });
        }
    }
```

HTML:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<%
console.log(data);
%>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you `console.log(html)` to check it works fine?

Comment: @iplus26 Yep, both data and html hold correct values right before the template code.

Comment: why do you have this ancient string? ` xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` ? it's a blast from the past

Comment: @vsync autogen'd by visual studio. I was three when that standard was made LOL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm new to underscore, but it works fine for me. Check what you've missed.

File Structure:

```
--test.html
--test.js
```

test.html

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<%
console.log(data, 'it works! ');
%>
</body>
</html>
```

test.js

```
var data = [], rows = [1,2,3,4];
var _ = require('underscore'),
    fs = require('fs');

for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
  data.push(rows[i]);
  if (i == rows.length - 1) {
    fs.readFile('test.html', 'utf8', function(err, html) {
      console.log(html); // correct html file content
      var template = _.template(html);
      var result = template({
        data: data // After console print the html file, 
                   // it runs the script code in html file, 
                   // which in my point of view, means `template` works. 
      });
      // res.send(result);
    });
  }
}
```

Run `node test.js` in the terminal, it works fine.

[image]

PS: I did `console.log(result)` and got the correct result:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```